# How to find the values in database values 1,2,3 with Query?

Tags: mysql

I have table in one field look like `1,32,31`. How to Exactly find on `id` in that field

```
SELECT *
FROM question_link_master
WHERE l_question_status <> 'D'
AND question_id
IN ( 24 )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Not clear ->  `one field lool like 1,32,31`..

Comment: be more clear with your question please

Comment: If you are storing data like `1,32,31` then I call it `Normaloporosis` and you need to normalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have an split function, you can build it yourself:
http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Or you can use a REGEXP matching (better solution):
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

regards.